# LTspice error, EKG

Tags: ltspice

I got these errors.  What should I do?

```
Circuit: * C:\Users\hp\Documents\LTspiceXVII\EKG Schaltung.asc

Error on line 10 : c3 n002 n009 470 pf
     Unknown parameter "pf"
Error on line 13 : c1 n005 n004 3.3 mu
     Unknown parameter "mu"
WARNING: Less than two connections to node NC_01.  This node is used by V1.
WARNING: Less than two connections to node NC_02.  This node is used by V2.
Direct Newton iteration for .op point succeeded.
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u3:1)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u3:2)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u4:1)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u4:2)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(lm324:1)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(lm324:2)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u1:1)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u1:2)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u3:1)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u3:2)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u4:1)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u4:2)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(lm324:1)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(lm324:2)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u1:1)
Ignoring empty pin current: Ix(u1:2)
Heightened Def Con from 1.01564e-006 to 1.01877e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.02352e-006 to 1.02752e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.02898e-006 to 1.03011e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.03275e-006 to 1.03675e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.04004e-006 to 1.04216e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.04346e-006 to 1.04646e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.04775e-006 to 1.05175e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.05866e-006 to 1.06066e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.06155e-006 to 1.06555e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.0693e-006 to 1.0733e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.08894e-006 to 1.09194e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.11181e-006 to 1.11581e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.18035e-006 to 1.18435e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.36509e-006 to 1.36909e-006
Heightened Def Con from 1.52071e-006 to 1.52271e-006
Heightened Def Con from 2.0028e-006 to 2.0098e-006
Heightened Def Con from 2.28336e-006 to 2.28736e-006
Heightened Def Con from 3.52574e-006 to 3.52786e-006
Heightened Def Con from 3.55417e-006 to 3.55817e-006
Heightened Def Con from 4.01314e-006 to 4.01714e-006
Heightened Def Con from 4.64992e-006 to 4.65392e-006
Heightened Def Con from 8.35414e-006 to 8.35452e-006
Heightened Def Con from 2.24585e-005 to 2.24615e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.72313e-005 to 2.72334e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.72977e-005 to 2.73017e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.7317e-005 to 2.7321e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.7325e-005 to 2.7329e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.73299e-005 to 2.73329e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.73343e-005 to 2.73383e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.73509e-005 to 2.73549e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.74325e-005 to 2.74365e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.74548e-005 to 2.74578e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.74949e-005 to 2.74989e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.75094e-005 to 2.75134e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.7772e-005 to 2.77742e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.77995e-005 to 2.78035e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78114e-005 to 2.78115e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78116e-005 to 2.78127e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78136e-005 to 2.78157e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78159e-005 to 2.78159e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.7816e-005 to 2.7817e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.7817e-005 to 2.78171e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78171e-005 to 2.78201e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78328e-005 to 2.78348e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.7835e-005 to 2.7838e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.7845e-005 to 2.7847e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78487e-005 to 2.78497e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78497e-005 to 2.785e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78502e-005 to 2.78522e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78524e-005 to 2.78526e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78526e-005 to 2.78556e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78559e-005 to 2.7856e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78561e-005 to 2.78591e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78606e-005 to 2.78609e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.7861e-005 to 2.7863e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78704e-005 to 2.78706e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78709e-005 to 2.78729e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.78885e-005 to 2.78905e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.79844e-005 to 2.79874e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80593e-005 to 2.80613e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80726e-005 to 2.80727e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80727e-005 to 2.80747e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80758e-005 to 2.80759e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.8076e-005 to 2.80761e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80761e-005 to 2.80765e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80774e-005 to 2.80774e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80775e-005 to 2.80786e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80787e-005 to 2.80807e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80807e-005 to 2.80808e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80809e-005 to 2.80811e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80826e-005 to 2.80828e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80828e-005 to 2.80849e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80864e-005 to 2.80874e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80875e-005 to 2.80885e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80885e-005 to 2.80885e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80886e-005 to 2.80886e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80886e-005 to 2.80896e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80896e-005 to 2.80916e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80949e-005 to 2.80969e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80974e-005 to 2.80975e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80975e-005 to 2.80987e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80998e-005 to 2.80999e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.80999e-005 to 2.81019e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81034e-005 to 2.81034e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81034e-005 to 2.81054e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81059e-005 to 2.81089e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81094e-005 to 2.81116e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81119e-005 to 2.8112e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.8112e-005 to 2.8114e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81154e-005 to 2.81154e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81154e-005 to 2.81166e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81172e-005 to 2.81173e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81173e-005 to 2.81173e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81173e-005 to 2.81176e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81176e-005 to 2.81186e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81186e-005 to 2.81206e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81209e-005 to 2.8121e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81213e-005 to 2.81233e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81237e-005 to 2.81239e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81239e-005 to 2.81259e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81307e-005 to 2.81318e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81318e-005 to 2.8133e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.8137e-005 to 2.8137e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.8137e-005 to 2.8139e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81411e-005 to 2.81433e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81434e-005 to 2.81435e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81435e-005 to 2.81445e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81445e-005 to 2.81448e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81448e-005 to 2.81458e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81458e-005 to 2.81469e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81469e-005 to 2.8147e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81471e-005 to 2.81472e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81472e-005 to 2.81483e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81483e-005 to 2.81486e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81488e-005 to 2.81489e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81489e-005 to 2.81501e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81518e-005 to 2.81538e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81541e-005 to 2.81543e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81544e-005 to 2.81544e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81544e-005 to 2.81556e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81556e-005 to 2.81556e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81556e-005 to 2.81556e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81556e-005 to 2.81556e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81556e-005 to 2.81556e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81556e-005 to 2.81576e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81576e-005 to 2.81596e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81597e-005 to 2.816e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.816e-005 to 2.8162e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81625e-005 to 2.81646e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81676e-005 to 2.81698e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81703e-005 to 2.81705e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81705e-005 to 2.81708e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81709e-005 to 2.81739e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81803e-005 to 2.81805e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.8181e-005 to 2.8183e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81832e-005 to 2.81852e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81861e-005 to 2.81873e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.81953e-005 to 2.81973e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82009e-005 to 2.82039e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82048e-005 to 2.82068e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82195e-005 to 2.82197e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82199e-005 to 2.822e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.822e-005 to 2.82204e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82208e-005 to 2.82228e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82228e-005 to 2.8223e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.8223e-005 to 2.8226e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82322e-005 to 2.82325e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82333e-005 to 2.82335e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82343e-005 to 2.82354e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82356e-005 to 2.82396e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82413e-005 to 2.82423e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82423e-005 to 2.82444e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82452e-005 to 2.82462e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82465e-005 to 2.82467e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82467e-005 to 2.82468e-005
Heightened Def Con from 2.82468e-005 to 2.82468e-005
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 10.5896 to 10.5896
Heightened Def Con from 11.0569 to 11.0569
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256
Heightened Def Con from 13.5256 to 13.5256

Date: Mon Nov 21 13:07:12 2022
Total elapsed time: 663.346 seconds.

tnom = 27
temp = 27
method = modified trap
totiter = 27705240
traniter = 27705208
tranpoints = 4930144
accept = 3398982
rejected = 1531378
matrix size = 95
fillins = 146
solver = Normal
Thread vector: 17.8/5.8[4] 4.8/3.4[4] 4.1/3.9[1] 0.8/3.2[1]  2592/500
Matrix Compiler1: 12.38 KB object code size  3.5/2.2/[1.1]
Matrix Compiler2: 8.99 KB object code size  1.6/1.9/[0.8]
```

[image]

Comment: Begin by fixing your errors (470 pF -> 470p, 3.3 mu -> 3.3m) and by connecting the negatives of V1 and V2 to ground.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I’m voting to close this question because asking for what is essentially an LTSpice tutorial is not an on-topic question.

Comment: Also similar question(s) posted by the OP but suggestions were ignored. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/643334/i-dont-know-what-to-do-to-get-a-sine-in-this-ltspice-circuit

Answer (score 4):

1. Your capacitor values are incorrectly specified (you need to write 470p and 3.3u rather than 470 pf and 3.3 mu)
2. The negative terminals of V1 and V2 aren't connected to anything.

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: @MaryamElYaagoubi what "doesn't work"? What error messages do you get after making the changes I said?

Comment: it should be sinus but it's not, idk why

Answer (score 3):

Your capacitor values are malformed: You have to remove the space in "470 pF" (otherwise it gets interpreted as multiple parameters, and ideally you just write "470p"), and use "µ" or "u" instead of "mu".

Comment: the "p" doesn't work

Comment: It most certainly does.

Comment: it supposed to be a sis but it's not, what can i do?

Comment: This is simply wrong and I'm very surprised that it got 3 upvotes for spreading false rumours. LTspice accepts any other letter after the metric prefix, and they will simply be ignored. What mattes is the first letter. The `mu` part is true, if OP meant `micro` (most probably).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen You're right, I was mistaken about why "pF" didn't work - it was the space, not the F. Thanks for pointing this out.